# Data load takes long using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm fetching data from an API. I'm using AngularJS as my front-end framework. The problem is that after landing on a page, it takes some unexpected number of seconds to load/resolve and display data.

This is part of my custom service,

```js
 all: function () {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          $http.get('/departments')
            .success(function (data) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (err) {
              deferred.reject(err);
            });

          return deferred.promise;
        },
```

Any guide, please on the fix?

Comment: Your code is really more complex than it should be, but if loading is slow, then it's either your network, or your server, or the amount of data to load that is a problem. Not the code you're showing. The code should just be `return $http.get('/departments').then(function(response) { return response.data; });`. Note that success and error are deprecated since 1.4, and removed since 1.6.

Comment: Maybe it is the amount of data. The network and server don't have any issue. Though I'm using the same technique to fetch some data which is also bulky but doesn't take too long to load.

Comment: The first thing you should do is use the dev tools to know what is taking time

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that. Will post here a solution if I get a fix.

Comment: Maybe the data is rendered slowly in the dom and not the request. Are you showing the data with an ng-repeat? How much data is?

Comment: Yes I'm using ng-repeat. The data is 579 rows in total